# How do I use regex for text on two separate lines at once?

Tags: notepad++, regex

Im fairly new to Regular Expression but I cant seem to get this right (even though it works on regex tester websites) it doesnt work on Notepad++.

Example RegEx (yes the "  " is a part of the string):

`foo  \nbar  \n`

Example text:

```
bar
sfjhsr
foo
bar
srhs
foo
```

Comment: Please note - MacOS, by default, uses a single carriage return (`<CR>`), represented as `\r`. Unix uses a single linefeed (`<LF>`), `\n`. Windows uses both, creating a (`<CRLF>`) combination, `\r\n`. You may want to try `foo  \Rbar  \R` for your needs.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: tysm ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: why are you sticking all those spaces in there and have you ticked the extended search box or the regex box? you don't even need a regex

Answer (score 1):

Use `\s` to match any space character, including space, tab, carriage return, new line, vertical tab and form feed.

Include the `+` modifier, so any number of characters will be matched.

**Your "Find what" field will look like `foo\s+bar`**

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your operating system.

Please note - *MacOS*, by default, uses a single carriage return (`<CR>`), represented as `\r`. *Unix* uses a single linefeed (`<LF>`), `\n`. *Windows* uses both, creating a (`<CRLF>`) combination, `\r\n`.

If you want to use RegEx try `foo  \Rbar  \R` for your needs.

The `\R` syntax means any kind of normal End of Line.

For further information see [RegEx info: More White-Space](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#whitespace)

Comment: can you state what \R does? And is this a code from BRE or ERE or PCRE or something notepad++ specific or what?

Comment: @barlop - see my edit.

Comment: Your link on \R is useful in mentioning that it's PCRE.  Going off that link's mention of PCRE, I see this page on PCRE gives more info  eg that it can match CR or LF or CRLF. 
 https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#newlineseq

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regex. though you can tick the regex box if you want .I ticked "extended" which is between normal and regex.

[image]